# Why is built-in AGE function slower than integer subtraction in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am tinkering with trying to improve a query that obtains the age of a person in years (assuming they are alive).

Originally there was

```sql
SELECT
    date_part('year', NOW())::integer - date_part('year', birth_date)::integer
FROM data_table;
```

but I tried this out

```sql
SELECT
    date_part('year', AGE(birth_date))::integer
FROM data_table;
```

It turns out that the former is faster by about 2-3 seconds (3 replicates). I would have guessed that using a built-in function would be faster, but that does not appear to be the case here. My first guess is that additional logic is being applied behind the scenes for the `AGE` function; maybe related to checking/casting types.

Why is the former query faster?

Comment: Those two queries are not equivalent.

Comment: @TheImpaler That sounds promising. Could you elaborate on why they are not equivalent?

Comment: See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=791ba1b510e691f746a777d6e0954b54. Depending on the month/day the second query returns different results (21) compared to the first one (22).

Answer (score 0):

As [The Impaler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6436191/the-impaler) demonstrates in his comment and fiddle, the functions are not equivalent. In addition to the year, the Age function also needs to take into consideration the month and day, which is probably why you notice that it is slower. If we add that into the calculation:

```
SELECT date_part('year', NOW())::integer - date_part('year', birth_date)::integer 
   - case when (date_part('month', NOW())::integer, date_part('day', NOW())::integer) 
             > (date_part('month', birth_date)::integer, date_part('day', birth_date)::integer)
     then 0 
     else 1
     end as manual_diff    
FROM data_table;
```

is it still faster than the age function?